# Is there a terraform resource which can force an intermediate update of the remote statefile, before continuing?

Tags: terraform, terraform-state

I set up terraform to use a backend to remotely store the statefile. That works fine.

My project take several minutes for the full `terraform apply` to complete. During development, sometimes one of the later stages hangs (seemingly) eternally. I need the outputs in order to manually connect to the servers and inspect what is broken. However, the statefile does not get written until the terraform process completes. So there are no outputs available during the first `terraform apply`.

Is there a way to make terraform update the statefile intermediately, while it is still busy applying things?

I know I could solve this by separating the process into multiple modules, and apply each one after the other. But I am looking for a solution where I can still apply all at once.

Comment: I think you are approaching this in a wrong way. The main question should be why does it hang. Is there something you can do about that first?

Comment: The main question is the main question. The hanging is just an example why one might want this. I could have left it out and just say "is there a way to get outputs while a long running `terraform apply` did not finish yet?".

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: I will happily mark your answer as accepted. I was afraid it was the case, but could not find confirmation or falsification.

Comment: Well, when the apply is running, there is no way you can pick up anything from the state, as I think it is not a complete state file. I don't have a confirmation, but I'm pretty sure that e.g., stopping the apply step can cause different issues. So that leads me to believe that there is not an easy and clean way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
terraform plan
```

you get the outputs also. What you can do is save that file before applying -

```
terraform plan -out tf.plan
```

Then you apply.
You can look into this file to find the changes.

> Remember, you won't find the output data that were to be showed after apply, like a thing that does not exist yet.

Best wishes.